# Wpf - Speed ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've got a Wpf Application and I'm having some speed/time issues. I've got a Grid with 2 columns. The left column contains a panel with a ListBox, and when one of the items is selected it creates a new panel and sets it at the right column of the Grid. So I've got a fixed panel on the left and a changing panel on the right.

My right panel contains some details and a ListBox. When I keep changing the right panel (change selection of the left panel) it gets really slow and UI freezes. I was able to find the issue, and it was with my ListBox. It has a complex ItemTemplate and this could explain why it is slow.

My ListBox ItemTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
        <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" FontSize="10" Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
            <Border Padding="8" CornerRadius="10,10,10,10" Background="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="{Binding Property}" Visibility="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="DemiBold" TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                        <Image Source="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" MaxWidth="800" MaxHeight="200" Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
                        <Image gif:ImageBehavior.AnimatedSource="ImageSource" Width="200" MaxHeight="200" Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                    <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding ., Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" Margin="0, 2, 0, 0" Visibility="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}">
            <Image Source="ImageSource" Margin="0,0,0,5" MaxHeight="10" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBox Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Text="{Binding Property, Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="10" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Given this, what are some ways to speed things up?

Comment: All of your binding is set to "Property" and uses your converter "MyConverter". Without seeing what MyConverter is doing, it is hard to say why it is slow. Also, it is not clear as why you would be binding to same property everywhere. Show your code for MyConverter.

Comment: MyConverter is used in HorizontalAlignment, Text, Source, Background. Nice. Presumably countless number of if statement inside. Converter's name should indicate its goal.

Comment: It is not the same converter and property I changed the names to simplify

Comment: @Daniel It is hard to determine your issue without the your code and rest of your xaml. Changing the name of things is not really helpful. A suggestion you could try using the [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) class in the logic of your converters to time the speed of your code and see if anything in there is taking a long time. I'd be curious about the converter on that one Image which is binding its source.